# how to do multiplication in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to multiply the price by the quantity to get the total cost but i am not sure how to do this.

This is what i have done so far:

```
<?php do { ?>
    <p align="Center"> 
        <?php echo $row3['unitprice'] ?> 
        <?php echo $row3['quantity']; ?>
    </p>
<?php } while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer3))?>
```

at the moment i am only printing out unit price and the quantity.

how would i multiply the two to get the total?

HELP please!!

Comment: Add a new Field to yyour query and multiply it in mysql and show simply the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php  while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer3)) {?>
<p align="Center"> 
    <?php echo $row3['unitprice']; ?> 
    <?php echo $row3['quantity']; ?>
    <?php echo $row3['quantity']*$row3['unitprice']; ?>
</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To multiply two fields in php, you need this code:

```php
$total = $mnth_190 * $rate_190;
```

After having calculated the result, you can normally output the variable *total*!